# Python used the decorator TypeError: bilolgy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.x

I've tried to define a decorator in a base class,and used it in a subclass,but when I ran it, then came out the wrong message. here is the code:

```
class Base(object):
    """
    base class
    """
    def bilolgy(self, pre):
        def animal(func):
            def color(a):
                print(pre)
                print("Today is a good day")
                func(a)

            return color

        return animal


class Sub(Base):
    """
    subclass
    """
    @Base.bilolgy(pre="Cats")
    def cat(self, name):
        print("This is a " + name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub = Sub()
    sub.cat("cat")
```

here is the wrong message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevin/test/sklearn/test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    class Sub(Base):
  File "/home/kevin/test/sklearn/test2.py", line 22, in Sub
    @Base.bilolgy(pre="Cats")
TypeError: bilolgy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

when I added a self into code like this:

```
@Base.bilolgy(self, pre="Cats")
```

another wrong message came out as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevin/test/sklearn/test2.py", line 18, in <module>
    class Sub(Base):
  File "/home/kevin/test/sklearn/test2.py", line 22, in Sub
    @Base.bilolgy(pre="Cats")
TypeError: bilolgy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Prefer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263782/1453822) answer rather than the accepted one in the dupe.

Comment: Decorators are pretty irrelevant here. You'd get the same issue trying to call any `Foo.bar()` instead of `Foo().bar()`.