# ray multiprocessing inside a class (TypeError: parameter lacking default value)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, default-value, ray

I'm trying to use the python multiprocess package [ray](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), to parallelise a convolution process from within a class.

This means I am setting the function using the `@ray.remote` decorator to a class function.

However when I do this I get an error to do with parameter defaults.

I am new to using ray and decorators so I was wondering if anyone has some advice on where I am going wrong because I don't think this is as simple as providing the class function with an optional default parameter such as `None` for example.

---

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import psutil
import ray
from astropy.convolution import convolve

class test_class:

    def __init__(self,cube):
        self.cube = cube

    @ray.remote
    def func(self, cube, psf):
        cube = convolve(cube, psf)
        return cube

    def calculation(self):

        num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False) 
        ray.shutdown()
        ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus)

        filters = np.array([[0,.5,0],[.5,.7,.5],[0,.5,0]]) 

        results =  []
        for i in range(self.cube.shape[2]):
            results.append(self.func.remote(self.cube[:,:,i],filters))  
        results = np.array(ray.get(results)).T

        ray.shutdown()

        return results
```

Running the code...

```
cube = np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,100,10))
new_cube = test_class(cube).calculation()
```

And the resulting error:

> TypeError: 'psf' parameter lacking default value

---

I found a similar post but I'm not sure if the two problems are that similar due to handling the execution of `ray` differently and my naivety on the use of this package.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This problem was solved by moving the class function:

```
@ray.remote
    def func(self, cube, psf):
        cube = convolve(cube, psf)
        return cube
```

...inside the class function `self.calculation`, and removing `self`

---

Update: The reason for why this fails can be seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263545/8188120)