# Why are there warnings in these decorated methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-decorators

I am string with decorators and the first use I have is to wrap a HTTP call to account for failed connections. The working code is as follows:

```
import requests

class Gotify:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://postman-echo.com/status/200"

    def ensure_safe_call(caller):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                r = caller(*args, **kwargs)
                r.raise_for_status()
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    print(f"cannot reach gotify: {e}: {r.text}")
                except NameError:
                    print(f"cannot reach gotify: {e} (the response r does not exist)")
            else:
                print("OK notified gotify of result change")

        return wrapper

    @ensure_safe_call
    def send(self, title, message):
        return requests.get(self.url)

Gotify().send("hello", "world")
```

This correct displays `OK notified gotify of result change`.

When editing this in PyCharm, I get two warning which I do not understand:

[image]

and

[image]

What do they mean in the context of my decorators (there are none when I do not use decorators)

Comment: This question already has answers here: [python-decorators-in-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263451)

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Gotify:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://postman-echo.com/status/200"

    def ensure_safe_call(caller):
```

Because `ensure_safe_call` is a class method, the first argument (in your case `caller`) is actually the `self` argument, the instance of the clas object--`Gotify`.

Hence the warning message about the `Gotify` object not being callable (it's not callable because you have not overridden the `__call__` class method in your `Gotify` class)

`Function ensure_safe_call lacks a positional argument` -- this is because `ensure_safe_call` only takes in the `self` argument, and doesn't specify any actual input arguments (recall that `caller == self` given the way you have it defined). Thus, your decorator `ensure_safe_call` cannot wrap anything, because it's accepting no position arguments.

You need to define a positional argument

```py
    def ensure_safe_call(self, caller):
        ...
```

Comment: When you say "cannot wrap anything" you mean that the code is wrong? I am surprised because it behaves correctly (for `https://postman-echo.com/status/200` and `https://postman-echo.com/status/400`, which cover both cases (the `print` and the `raise`))

Comment: By "cannot wrap anything" i mean you cannot use that function to decorate another function.  The function you decorate is passed as a positional argument to the decorator function--`ensure_safe_call` is a class function, so the *very first* argument implicitly passed to it is the instance of the object (conventionally called "self")--in your case, it's called `caller`. You need to add another argument to `ensure_safe_call`, the second argument will be the function decorated. `def ensure_safe_call(self, caller):`

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I tried your solution and i) the warnings are gone but ii) the code does not work anymore :) (`TypeError: ensure_safe_call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'caller'`). My code in the example does work, though. So I am quite confused - especially that you clearly make a point.

Comment: Well, to avoid this problem, you should make `ensure_afe_call` a tatic function (bring it outside the class). The way its written, it *is* a static function--moving it outide your class and keeping the signature `ensure_safe_call(caller)` will give you the result you're looking for. In my experience, I've never seen a decorator as a class function before. I've only seen them as static functions