# Decorator arguments lost in self

Tags: python-3.x, decorator

I have a decorator

```py
class Utilities(commands.Cog):
    def has_any_role(self, *items):
        async def predicate(ctx):
            ctx.command.needed_roles = items
            return await commands.has_any_role(*items).predicate(ctx)
        return commands.check(predicate)

    @has_any_role('Owner', 'Moderator')
    @commands.command()
    async def foo(...):
        ...
```

However now when I try to access a `Command`s `needed_roles` attribute, it'll only return Moderator for `foo`, since `"Owner"` is lost in self. How can I fix this without just putting the function outside of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@staticmethod
def has_any_role(*items)
...
```

Comment: I already tried that, you can't call a staticmethod. same with classmethod

Comment: Of course--it is a descriptor-like thing at that point.  (You could have mentioned that you tried that in the first place :-). At any rate, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263451/python-decorators-in-classes) answers your question--basically, just leave out self in the method definition.