# Apply decorators class to methods of another class

Tags: python, oop, decorator

I'm learning about decorators and what I'm trying to do is to apply a simple decorator class to methods of another class for understanding and educational purposes.

```
class decorators():
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'this method has been decorated')
        return self.func(self,*args, **kwargs)

class Users():
    def __init__(self,name,password,age,email):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.age = age
        self.email = email

    @decorators
    def login(self):
        name = input('Enter your name')
        password = input('Enter your password')
        if name == self.name and password == self.password:
            print("user logged in")
        else:
            print("wrong credentials")

    @decorators
    def show(self):
        print(f'my name is {self.name} and my age is {self.age}')

user1 = Users('John', 'pass', 20, 'john@doe.com')
user1.login()
```

As you can see, I just want to test whether I can build this decorator class that calls any methods in the Users class such as login() and show(). When calling user1.login() as above, I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-ed78c0a45454> in <module>
----> 1 user1.login()

<ipython-input-96-759e600a717b> in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      5     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      6         print(f'this method has been decorated')
----> 7         return self.func(self,*args, **kwargs)
      8 
      9 class Users():

<ipython-input-96-759e600a717b> in login(self)
     18         name = input('Enter your name')
     19         password = input('Enter your password')
---> 20         if name == self.name and password == self.password:
     21             print("user logged in")
     22         else:

AttributeError: 'decorators' object has no attribute 'name'
```

My thinking is that the User instance is not passed to the decorator and thus the decorator object doesn't have the User attribute 'name'. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263451/python-decorators-in-classes

Comment: You are passing `self` to the first argument of `self.func`: `return self.func(self,*args, **kwargs)` but `self` is a `decorator` instance, not an instance of `Users`, hence the error

Comment: "My thinking is that the User instance is not passed to the decorator and thus the decorator object doesn't have the User attribute 'name;" why would the `decorator` object *ever* have the attributes of  another object?

Comment: Thanks guys. I understand why the problem occurs now

Comment: @Alice_inwonderland actually, check my edit, I meant to pass `self` to MethodType and to *not* use `self` in `decorators.__call__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `self` to the first argument of `self.func`: `return self.func(self,*args, **kwargs)` but `self` is a `decorator` instance, not an instance of `Users`, hence the error.

There are various ways to make this work. Essentially, the instance is passed as the first argument to a function object when it is called on that instance through the [*descriptor protocol*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods)

That is, function objects are descriptors, and their `__get__` method partially applies the instance to itself. So the cleanest way to make your custom class act like a function object is to make your `decorator` class a descriptor, replicating what a function object does:

```
from types import MethodType
class decorators:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'this method has been decorated')
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return MethodType(self, obj)
```

So, as an example:

```
>>> from types import MethodType
>>> class decorators:
...     def __init__(self, func):
...         self.func = func
...     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         print(f'this method has been decorated')
...         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
...     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
...         if obj is None:
...             return self
...         return MethodType(self, obj)
...
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.bar = 42
...     @decorators
...     def frobnicate(self):
...         return self.bar + 1
...
>>> Foo().frobnicate()
this method has been decorated
43
```