# Mocking class methods, still running the original method with some wrapped code

Tags: python, pandas, testing, mocking, pyfakefs

I want to patch a method by running the original method with additional code before and after. In particular, I'm running tests within a `pyfakefs` in-memory file system, but I want to sometime use the real file system because some packages will not work on the fake file system (`pybedtools` in my case).

There is probably simple way to do this, but I can't figure it out after many, many tries. Is this possible?

Just for an example, below I'm trying to patch `to_csv` in pandas.

```
import os
import tempfile
from unittest.mock import patch
import pandas as pd
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import Patcher


df_intervals = pd.DataFrame([
     ['1', 10, 20],
     ['20', 45, 55]],
     columns=['chrom', 'start', 'end'])


with Patcher(use_known_patches=True) as patcher:
    # As expecte writing to fake filesystem works
    fname = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    df_intervals.to_csv(fname.name)
    assert not os.path.exists(fname.name)
    assert patcher.fs.isfile(fname.name)

    # But, how do I patch `to_csv` to write to the real filesystem? My failed attempts:
    # Attempt 1
    # TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
    class patched_DataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
        def to_csv(self, fname):
            print('Pausing fake file system')
            patcher.pause()
            super().to_csv(fname)
            print('Resuming fake file system')
            patcher.resume()

    with patch.object(pd.core.generic.NDFrame, 'to_csv', new=patched_DataFrame.to_csv):
        df_intervals.to_csv(fname.name)

    # Attempt 2: TypeError: 'patched_DataFrame' object is not callable
    with patch('pandas.core.frame.DataFrame', new_callable=patched_DataFrame):
        df_intervals.to_csv(fname.name)

    # Attempt 3: infinite recursion
    def patched_to_csv(self, fname):
        print('Pausing fake file system')
        patcher.pause()
        self.to_csv(fname)
        print('Resuming fake file system')
        patcher.resume()

    with patch.object(pd.core.generic.NDFrame, 'to_csv', new=patched_to_csv):
        df_intervals.to_csv(fname.name)
```

Comment: using decorator? like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1263782/3214422)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (not very elegant) possibility would be to use the third approach and avoid the recursion by using the old saved `to_csv` method:

```py
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import Patcher, Pause


with Patcher() as patcher:
    ...

    def patched_to_csv(self, fname):
        with Pause(patcher.fs):
            original_to_csv(self, fname)

    original_to_csv = pd.core.generic.NDFrame.to_csv
    with patch.object(pd.core.generic.NDFrame, 'to_csv', new=patched_to_csv):
        df_intervals.to_csv(fname.name)
```

Note that I used the context manager for pause/resume - this would allow to easily propagate a return value of the patches function if needed and is less error-prone.
Also note that `use_known_patches` is `True` by default.

*Disclaimer*:
I'm a contributor to `pyfakefs`.

*Update*: I changed the answer, because the previous attempt to avoid the recursion was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

```
df_intervals = pd.DataFrame([
     ['1', 10, 20],
     ['20', 45, 55]],
     columns=['chrom', 'start', 'end'])


def fakefs_decorator(func, patcher):
    """ Force a method to work on the real filesystem """
    def fs_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        patcher.pause()
        out = func(*args, **kwargs)
        patcher.resume()
        return out

    if hasattr(func, '__self__'):
        def c_wrapper(_, *args, **kwargs):
            return fs_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        return classmethod(c_wrapper)
    return fs_wrapper


with Patcher(allow_root_user=False, use_known_patches=True) as patcher:
    fs_from_dataframe = fakefs_decorator(pybedtools.BedTool.from_dataframe, patcher)
    fs_to_dataframe = fakefs_decorator(pybedtools.BedTool.to_dataframe, patcher)
    fs_intersect = fakefs_decorator(pybedtools.BedTool.intersect, patcher)

    @patch('pybedtools.BedTool.from_dataframe', new=fs_from_dataframe)
    @patch('pybedtools.bedtool.BedTool.to_dataframe', new=fs_to_dataframe)
    @patch('pybedtools.bedtool.BedTool.intersect', new=fs_intersect)
    def test(df_intervals):
        bed_object = pybedtools.BedTool.from_dataframe(df_intervals)
        joined_bed_object = bed_object.intersect(bed_object)
        df = joined_bed_object.to_dataframe()
        return df

    df = test(df_intervals)
```

Comment: Hadn't seen your answer while I corrected my own - I like the decorator approach, and also it is more generic.

Comment: Your use of the Pause context manager is cleaner. When I combine it with the decorator, I'm pretty happy with the result. Thanks for the help!